# Gremlin Console: JSON response doesn't work

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm trying to access a remote Gremlin server with version `3.0.0` using a Gremlin console `3.0.0`. The serializer I'm using is `GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0`.

When I run this, I get an error message:

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.sugar
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
plugin activated: aurelius.titan
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-json.yaml
==>Connected - localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :> graph.traversal().V(4128)
```

I get this error:

```
Server could not serialize the result requested. Server error - Error during serialization: (was java.lang.IllegalStateException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier["inVertexId"]). Note that the class must be serializable by the client and server for proper operation.
Display stack trace? [yN] y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Server could not serialize the result requested. Server error - Error during serialization: (was java.lang.IllegalStateException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier["inVertexId"]). Note that the class must be serializable by the client and server for proper operation.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:110)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:134)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:292)
gremlin>
```

The configuration file for the console is:

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer:  { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0 }
```

And the server is:

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
threadPoolWorker: 1
gremlinPool: 8
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
serializedResponseTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/test_titan_isdb.properties}
plugins:
  - aurelius.titan
  - tinkerpop.tinkergraph
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    imports: [java.lang.Math],
    staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI],
    scripts: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]},
  nashorn: {
      imports: [java.lang.Math],
      staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI]}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0 }                                             # application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}   # application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-stringd
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0 }                                  # application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+json
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0 }                                         # application/json
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  gangliaReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, addressingMode: MULTICAST},
  graphiteReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
threadPoolBoss: 1
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
ssl: {
  enabled: false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the gremlin-server.yaml, you need to include the serializer config setting to use Titan's mappers. Check out the [gremlin-server.yaml](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml#L21-L24) that is shipped with the [titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip)

```
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { useMapperFromGraph: graph }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { useMapperFromGraph: graph }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { useMapperFromGraph: graph }}
```

The `useMapperFromGraph` key references back to `graph` you defined earlier in the gremlin-server.yaml in the `graphs` map. The properties file defines the TitanGraph, which uses custom serializers.

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/test_titan_isdb.properties}
```

You can read more about this configuration setting in the TinkerPop3 Gremlin Server [documentation](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#_serialization_2).